# how to make the 'animate' run the opposite direction using jquery 

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

this is my code:

```
$('#map_canvas').animate({width:'69.8%'},300);
```

this will run from left to right ,

how to make it from right to left ?

thanks

Comment: To be clear, do you want `#map_canvas` to grow to 69.8%, but growing from right to left, rather than left to right?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
$('#map_canvas').each(function() {
  var newLeft = $(this).width() * .302;
  $(this).animate({left: newLeft, width:'69.8%'},300);
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/yXBUL/1/), I slowed it down 10x to better see the effect.  All we're doing is calculating the width of the element * 30.2% to see how far left it should move and animating that property at the same time.  All the element needs is to be at least  `position: relative` for this to work.

The above should work in all cases, but this simpler version will work in *most* cases as well:

```
$('#map_canvas').animate({left: '30.2%', width:'69.8%'}, 300);
```

Answer (score 0):

To slide it back from right to left, make its width 0 again:

```
$('#map_canvas').animate({width:'0'},300);
```